# Making sure entire drawing area is visible when saving SVG in svgwrite

Tags: python, svg

I am constructing a chart and I have to put svg text on the left side of the chart. I am putting it at the point I want it to end in the chart with:

```
text_element = svgwrite.text.Text(
    "Label", 
    x=pos_x,
    y=pos_y, 
    fill=text_color)
text_element["text-anchor"] = "end"
dwg.add(text_element)
```

But I am ending up with only a part of text rendering in svg, while the rest being cut. I can use inkscape to set the area back to the area of the drawing.

Does svgwrite have a method to make sure the entire drawing area is visible?

An example svg with this problem is:

```
Preview:
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <svg baseProfile="tiny" version="1.2" width="500" height="290" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" transform="translate(46, -20)">
      <text fill="red" text-anchor="middle" x="14" y="70">9</text>
      <line stroke="rgb(10%,10%,16%)" x1="14" x2="14" y1="74" y2="79.12" />
      <line stroke="rgb(10%,10%,16%)" x1="47.1856" x2="47.1856" y1="74" y2="245.0" />
      <line stroke="rgb(10%,10%,16%)" x1="14" x2="47.1856" y1="245.0" y2="245.0" />
      <text fill="red" text-anchor="end" x="14" y="245.0">CLR</text>
      <text fill="red" text-anchor="middle" x="35" y="70">8</text>
      <line stroke="rgb(10%,10%,16%)" x1="35" x2="35" y1="74" y2="79.12" />
      <line stroke="rgb(10%,10%,16%)" x1="59.6288" x2="59.6288" y1="74" y2="213.5" />
      <line stroke="rgb(10%,10%,16%)" x1="14" x2="59.6288" y1="213.5" y2="213.5" />
      <text fill="red" text-anchor="end" x="14" y="213.5">RAKEL1</text>
      <text fill="red" text-anchor="middle" x="56" y="70">7</text>
      <line stroke="rgb(10%,10%,16%)" x1="56" x2="56" y1="74" y2="79.12" />
      <line stroke="rgb(10%,10%,16%)" x1="70.0" x2="70.0" y1="74" y2="182.0" />
      <line stroke="rgb(10%,10%,16%)" x1="14" x2="70.0" y1="182.0" y2="182.0" />
      <text fill="red" text-anchor="end" x="14" y="182.0">BPMLL</text>
      <text fill="red" text-anchor="middle" x="77" y="70">6</text>
      <line stroke="rgb(10%,10%,16%)" x1="77" x2="77" y1="74" y2="79.12" />
      <line stroke="rgb(10%,10%,16%)" x1="88.6666666667" x2="88.6666666667" y1="74" y2="150.5" />
      <line stroke="rgb(10%,10%,16%)" x1="14" x2="88.6666666667" y1="150.5" y2="150.5" />
      <text fill="red" text-anchor="end" x="14" y="150.5">MLkNN</text>
      <text fill="red" text-anchor="middle" x="98" y="70">5</text>
      <line stroke="rgb(10%,10%,16%)" x1="98" x2="98" y1="74" y2="79.12" />
      <line stroke="rgb(10%,10%,16%)" x1="123.926133333" x2="123.926133333" y1="74" y2="276.5" />
      <line stroke="rgb(10%,10%,16%)" x1="182.0" x2="123.926133333" y1="276.5" y2="276.5" />
      <text fill="red" text-anchor="start" x="182.0" y="276.5">RAKEL2</text>
      <text fill="red" text-anchor="middle" x="119" y="70">4</text>
      <line stroke="rgb(10%,10%,16%)" x1="119" x2="119" y1="74" y2="79.12" />
      <line stroke="rgb(10%,10%,16%)" x1="128.073866667" x2="128.073866667" y1="74" y2="245.0" />
      <line stroke="rgb(10%,10%,16%)" x1="182.0" x2="128.073866667" y1="245.0" y2="245.0" />
      <text fill="red" text-anchor="start" x="182.0" y="245.0">LP</text>
      <text fill="red" text-anchor="middle" x="140" y="70">3</text>
      <line stroke="rgb(10%,10%,16%)" x1="140" x2="140" y1="74" y2="79.12" />
      <line stroke="rgb(10%,10%,16%)" x1="140.518933333" x2="140.518933333" y1="74" y2="213.5" />
      <line stroke="rgb(10%,10%,16%)" x1="182.0" x2="140.518933333" y1="213.5" y2="213.5" />
      <text fill="red" text-anchor="start" x="182.0" y="213.5">BR</text>
      <text fill="red" text-anchor="middle" x="161" y="70">2</text>
      <line stroke="rgb(10%,10%,16%)" x1="161" x2="161" y1="74" y2="79.12" />
      <line stroke="rgb(10%,10%,16%)" x1="144.666666667" x2="144.666666667" y1="74" y2="182.0" />
      <line stroke="rgb(10%,10%,16%)" x1="182.0" x2="144.666666667" y1="182.0" y2="182.0" />
      <text fill="red" text-anchor="start" x="182.0" y="182.0">mlg-lp-unweighted</text>
      <text fill="red" text-anchor="middle" x="182" y="70">1</text>
      <line stroke="rgb(10%,10%,16%)" x1="182" x2="182" y1="74" y2="79.12" />
      <line stroke="rgb(10%,10%,16%)" x1="163.333333333" x2="163.333333333" y1="74" y2="150.5" />
      <line stroke="rgb(10%,10%,16%)" x1="182.0" x2="163.333333333" y1="150.5" y2="150.5" />
      <text fill="red" text-anchor="start" x="182.0" y="150.5">mlg-lp</text>
      <line stroke="orange" x1="163.333333333" x2="128.073866667" y1="83.87" y2="83.87" />
      <line stroke="orange" x1="163.333333333" x2="163.333333333" y1="81.245" y2="86.495" />
      <line stroke="orange" x1="128.073866667" x2="128.073866667" y1="81.245" y2="86.495" />
      <line stroke="orange" x1="144.666666667" x2="123.926133333" y1="94.37" y2="94.37" />
      <line stroke="orange" x1="144.666666667" x2="144.666666667" y1="91.745" y2="96.995" />
      <line stroke="orange" x1="123.926133333" x2="123.926133333" y1="91.745" y2="96.995" />
      <line stroke="orange" x1="140.518933333" x2="70.0" y1="104.87" y2="104.87" />
      <line stroke="orange" x1="140.518933333" x2="140.518933333" y1="102.245" y2="107.495" />
      <line stroke="orange" x1="70.0" x2="70.0" y1="102.245" y2="107.495" />
      <text fill="orange" x="14" y="35.0">Critical distance 0.38272</text>
      <line stroke="orange" x1="14" x2="78.2973333333" y1="42" y2="42" />
      <line stroke="orange" x1="14" x2="14" y1="38.5" y2="45.5" />
      <line stroke="orange" x1="78.2973333333" x2="78.2973333333" y1="38.5" y2="45.5" />
      <line stroke="rgb(10%,10%,16%)" x1="14" x2="182.0" y1="78.62" y2="78.62" />
    </svg>
```

Edit: seems inkscape did not fix, the problem, but the question is still valid, can I make the entire drawing area visible?

Comment: Have a good look at this: --------> https://pythonhosted.org/svgwrite/classes/mixins.html

Comment: So, one of the solutions I came up with is doing:

`dwg.viewbox(0,0,1000,1000)
dwg.fit("center","top","meet")`

Then using inkscape I can get a  PDF non-clipped, but tighly sized around the drawing for latex files etc. But:

1. arbitrarily using 1000 seems a mistake
2. I'd love it to be just right, not too much in the center, or whatnot

I was thinking about just running a bisection method loop too see if the pixel X pixels from the left is not text, but that is a poorer's machine vision choice of brute force.